# GraalVM and Swing

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I've read a few posts that GraalVM doesn't (or didn't) work building a Swing application. Can GraalVM build a Swing application?

I have an application that implements a simple terminal window that is implemented in Swing and uses JFrame, and menu items etc.

I downloaded the CE edition of GraalVM [`graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2`] and am building on a Linux Mint21 machine.

I'm using the [Maven plugin](https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html) and added the `<profiles>` block as discussed in this article.

The build command is:

```
mvn -Pnative -DskipTests package -f pom_graalvm.xml
```

The reported build errors are of the form:

```
Error encountered while parsing sun.awt.X11.XMenuItemPeer.repaintIfShowing()

Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported type sun.awt.X11.XBaseWindow is reachable
 
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.DeletedElementException: Unsupported type sun.awt.X11.XBaseWindow is reachable
```

Here is the start of the Terminal build errors:

```
1/7] Initializing...                                                                                   (12.9s @ 0.22GB)
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.2 Java 17 CE'
 Java version info: '17.0.7+7-jvmci-22.3-b18'
 C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 11.3.0)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC
[2/7] Performing analysis...  []                                                                        (18.0s @ 0.81GB)
   4,413 (83.53%) of  5,283 classes reachable
   6,242 (51.97%) of 12,011 fields reachable
  17,844 (76.05%) of 23,464 methods reachable
     176 classes,     0 fields, and     0 methods registered for reflection
       2 native libraries: m, stdc++

Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing sun.awt.X11.XMenuItemPeer.repaintIfShowing() 
Parsing context:
   at sun.awt.X11.XMenuItemPeer.repaintIfShowing(XMenuItemPeer.java:300)
   at sun.awt.X11.XMenuItemPeer.setEnabled(XMenuItemPeer.java:165)
   at java.awt.MenuItem.enable(MenuItem.java:309)
   at java.awt.MenuItem.enable(MenuItem.java:324)
   at java.awt.MenuItem.setEnabled(MenuItem.java:297)
...
```

*** Update Following Comment ***

Added to the POM:

```
            <configuration>
            ...
            <agent>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </agent>
            <jvmArgs>
                <arg>-Djava.awt.headless=false</arg>
            </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
```

New error log:

```
...
/usr/bin/ld: qis.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.svm_heap'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.handleLinkerFailure(NativeImageViaCC.java:203)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.runLinkerCommand(NativeImageViaCC.java:151)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.write(NativeImageViaCC.java:117)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:718)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
...
```

*** Runtime Errors Using graalvm-jdk-17.0.7+8.1 And Using /META-INF ***

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:136)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:50)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1388)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1386)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1385)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1423)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:579)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(ImageIcon.java:147)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(ImageIcon.java:145)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon.createNoPermsComponent(ImageIcon.java:144)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(ImageIcon.java:123)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(ImageIcon.java:120)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<clinit>(ImageIcon.java:120)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.desktop@17.0.7/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:215)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Djava.awt.headless=false` to your `native-image` invocation. This property is `true` by default, which doesn't work for GUI apps.

Also be sure to run agent beforehand, as AWT/Swing apps tend to rely on reflection extensively.

Comment: Thanks - I did as you suggested and have updated the original post with my changes. It got a bit further but still failed.

Comment: Looks like I've hit on what others have found: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4594. They seem to report it as fixed - not sure about that.

Comment: Tried Oracle GraalVM 17.0.7+8.1 and it did build successfully.

Comment: Doesn't run because not generating the /resources/META-INF

Comment: Added a /resources/META-INF and now get further runtime issues - see updated original post.

Comment: Another well-reported error: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2842

Comment: I can get the Oracle version of GraalVM /Java17 to build by setting headless. However, it fails when running. I then tried adding [java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()] to main(). You then get new errors of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path], etc. This all seems a bit too hacky and crap to me. My app actually supports both headless and non-headless and doubt even if I got a GraalVM build to work/run, the app's fundamental usage would have been changed. I use system-tray and others see the same [https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2842].